# c# Substring characters in a string

Tags: c#, substring

I have **string** value  below,

```
string value = "034 TH4493";
```

In first side,

```
var result = value.Substring(2,value.Length - 2);
```

In second side,

```
var result2 = value.Substring(0, 2);
```

**result1** must be

```
"34TH4493"
```

**result2** must be

```
34
```

However its not working for me and I can not solve the problem. Do I need to use another solution or what's missing in the above code ?

Thanks.

Comment: "it is not working for me" is *never* enough detail. What are you actually seeing compared with what you expected to see? How do you expect the space to be removed? How did you expect to get the "3" (which is at index 1) when you're using `value.Substring(2, ...)`?

Comment: What does it do currently that you aren't expecting? I'm guessing you are getting an out of bounds error and `03`?

Comment: how about reading the documentation of Substring method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = value.Substring(2, value.Length - 2);
```

There you're actually telling it to start at index position 2 (the 4 in "034 TH4493") and then to add as many characters as the length of "034 TH4493" (10, the space counts) minus 2, which would equal 8, thus: "4 TH4493".

What you want is to tell it to remove the space by replacing it with nothing, then start at index 1, so that the "0" at index 0 is discarded, then count for all other characters except the one you're ignoring:

```
var result = value.Replace(" ", "").Substring(1, value.Length - 2); // -2 because "value" holds both the space and the first 0, rather than just the 0
```

As you may imagine by now, `var result2 = value.Substring(0, 2);` is actually grabbing the "03" (index 0, two characters), when you'd actually want `var result2 = value.Substring(1, 2)`.

Alternatively, you could split the string, then grab whatever you want:

```
var result = value.Replace(" ", "").Substring(1, value.Length - 2);

var values = value.Split(' '); // Split at the space character
var result2 = values[0];
// or
var result2 = value.Split(' ')[0];
```

In cases like these, where you're unsure of what's going on, it helps to add breakpoints (F9 key with the default settings), so the application pauses when that line of code is reached, and you can explore the current values by hovering the cursor over the variables, or checking in the "Locals" tab.

EDIT: I ended mixing up the values you wanted for result and result2, should be fixed now...

Answer (score 1):

```
string v2 = value.TrimStart('0');            

var result1 = v2.Replace(" ","");

var result2 = v2.Split(' ')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find them as;

```
var result1 = value.Substring(1).Replace(" ", "");
var result2 = value.Substring(1, 2);
```

Need to replace your white space because it doesn't *magically* disappear. If you wanna get `"34TH4493"` instead of `34TH4493` as a *string*, you can format it like;

```
result1 = string.Format("\"{0}\"", result1);
```

Comment: Did I miss the question? o.O

Answer (score 0):

You must consider that the *index* for first character is *zero* not `1` for string.

*First case*

So first results starts from 3rd character but you want from second character to starting index would be 1 and ending index would be one less than the length.

```
var result = value.Substring(1,value.Length - 1);
```

*Second case*

For second you started from zero and want the to start from second character so started index should be `1` instead of `0`.

```
var result2 = value.Substring(1, 2);
```

You must read the documentation of [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) where [startIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) is "The zero-based starting character position of a substring in this instance"